# Which Fiasco playset resembles Pulp Fiction?

Tags: fiasco

Fiasco is an RPG creating movie tropes. There are playsets for all genres, from horror to western to romance. Is there one that matches the vibes of Tarantino Pulp Fiction (i.e. a dark satiric gangser imbroglio)?

Comment: As a product identification it would be allowable, but as a shopping question not.

Comment: I don't think this is appropriate to close. This is asking for a recommendation, but it's not a game rec request. It's pertinent that game recs failed because they always surfaced the same set of crowd favourites and answers often weren't justified. This just isn't that kind of question. It's well-constrained & can receive good answers. D&D players get to ask for recommendations about what what part of the game will help them solve their problem. Why doesn't a Fiasco player get to ask which available playset in their game's domain will help them approach a particular narrative?

Comment: @doppelgreener D&D adventure recommendations are regularly closed as shopping questions even if requirements are clear and question can be answered objectively? Why Fiasco should be exempt from no shopping questions rule?

Comment: @Molot because Fiasco is a pan-genre system about purely dramatic play that encompasses a vast variety in its playsets, from slasher to wuxia, sportsball to suburbia, "city comma state" to "CYBER.COMA.STATIC", and as per my answer, the components of the playset are usually credited to some inspiring media when possible. "a Fiasco playset that does Pulp Fiction" is pretty much a product identification, like "a D&D module featuring Bluedor the Gold from the 1987-89 Lost Orb series by Weena Mercator" (I have made this up).

Comment: @Mołot Because those questions are closed incorrectly because the decision to ban shopping questions has been wildly mis-applied and over-construed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Oddly enough, there are none that explicitly do.

*Fiasco* playsets wear their influences on their sleeve - literally. A standard part of every playset PDF is its **Movie Night** section, which mentions the various forms of media that inspired the elements that went into the playset.

I checked my personal collection of playset books and the [Bully Pulpit site](https://bullypulpitgames.com/games/fiasco/fiasco-playsets/), and there wasn't a playset with Pulp Fiction listed under Movie Night.

#### But you could do worse than *Run, Fools, Run*.

An official Bully Pulpit release (though PDF only) *Run, Fools, Run* is a series of three connected playsets: *The Last Heist*, which is what it sounds like, *White Line Fever*, the rickety getaway drive afterwards, and *The Murderists*, who stalk down the white line and clean up the mess.

*The Last Heist* puts Reservoir Dogs in its Movie Night section, and while Pulp Fiction doesn't explicitly show up in *The Murderists*, it's absolutely got some murderists in it.